# Is 2 1/4 x 3 1/4sheet film still availiable, or will I have to purchase 4x5 and cut it down?

Tags: film, large-format

I'm thinking of purchasing a Baby Speed Graphics Press Camera, it's smaller than the Speed Graphics and takes 2 1/4 x 3 1/4 film. I have a 4x5 camera but it's a big monorail camera that weighs a lot, needs a tripod, and I need to put my head under a blanket to take a photo. I want to start taking large format street photography, so I've been looking for a press camera, this fully functional Baby Speed Graphics is like 1/3 of the price of 4x5 cameras that are being sold for parts or repair, so I'm tempted, but if there is no film for it then it's useless.

Comment: You don't *have* to put your head under a blanket to take a photo. You could just "point and hope" with the 4X5 the same as will be required when using a press camera with no glass screen or other method of seeing the scene through the lens of the camera. [Like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfENk.jpg)

Comment: @MichaelClark I just *knew* the Weegee photograph would make it into this conversation - it is so iconic! But yes, the guy who coined "f8 and be there" phrase has something to teach us about focusing...

Answer (score 2):

The smallest sheet film that I know that is still being manufactured is [Foma 6.4 × 8.9 cm](https://fomaobchod.cz/blackwhitenegativefilms/sheetfilms/fomapan100sheets/fomapan10064x89cm50ks%5B11179%5D?ItemIdx=11), which is about 2.5 × 3.5 inches. Whether this would fit your camera is a question.

Also a question is whether you could get enough holders and an enlarger (such tiny contacts would likely not cut it...)

You might be better off with a regular size press camera with a rangefinder - such as the Mamiya Press.